# Proper format for tags

Tags: discussion, tags, formatting

I noticed a pattern in tags from [CSTheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ds.algorithms), which consists of adding an abbreviation before the name of an area. For example, if the tag is `probability`, they write down `pr-probability`, and so on for `ds.data-structures`, `db.databases`, `ds.algorithms`, `dc.distributed-comp`. Should we do the same? Anyone knows of pros/cons of doing so?

Comment: This is only a guess... but, these codes might be inspired by arXiv categories.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson These codes *are* [ArXiv categories](http://arxiv.org/corr/subjectclasses).

Comment: [Similar discussion on CS.SE](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6/using-acm-or-arxiv-based-tags). We didn't end up using these tags on [cs.se] because unlike on [cstheory.se], there wasn't a large enough proportion of the audience who already knew them and would use and enforce them naturally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No - tags should not *be* a puzzle, they should *categorize* a puzzle.

Tags inevitably become something that need to change over time, but, .....

.... I was going to say something derogatory about that tag taxonomy you describe on CSTheory, but, as I looked in to CSTheory to see how it works, I realized *I don't understand how it works*.... and, I think that is the bottom line:

- how would it work? What problem does it solve?
- if it is not easy to understand the *tags* on CSTheory, how can it possibly be a good thing?

So, no. K.I.S.S ..... ;-)

Comment: Well, the questions you pointed are the *pros/cons* I'd also like to know. I don't know why/what for they do that, but since they do, I thought there might would be some reason.

Comment: @Rubens - Tags should be the most simple mechanism for site organization. If you need to do research to understand how the tags work, then they are broken..... that's what i am trying to communicate in my answer.

Comment: Why would you say anything derogatory about this tag taxonomy? On [cstheory.se] (and [mathoverflow.se], which did it before), it is not a puzzle: it is familiar to the core audience of the site (researchers in CS). These tag names are [categories used on ArXiv](http://arxiv.org/corr/subjectclasses). It makes perfect sense there. On [cs.se], we considered and rejected it because a majority of the audience are not researchers and are not familiar with this classification. I think [datascience.se] is more like [cs.se] than [cstheory.se] — but it isn't a stupid suggestion.

Comment: @Gilles - I think your explanation of what the tags are and how they work....  reinforces the fact that they are not suitable for puzzling, and that the reference-perspective you need to use the tags effectively is acquired, not intuitive. How could that be a good thing? Especially on puzzling?

Comment: @rolfl Oh, uh, I think I understand what you're saying. Please note that we're on [meta.datascience.se], not on [meta.puzzling.se].

Comment: @Gilles - well, this is ... embarrassing, but still applies. There's no good way for me to dig myself out of this hole, so, I'll just wait for time to fill it in....